# Various test that can be used to know how secure a hashing/encryption algorithm can be

Tags: encryption, hash, aes, bcrypt

I am currently writing a paper in order to test how to secure a file using aes and bcrypt. I am highly interested to know how secure the aes key if I encrypt it with bcrypt, I have searched everywhere yet I still dont find a definite answer on how to test the security of bcrypt algorithm if used for encryption.
I have considered to use brute force because there is a bcrypt thesis from author Toras Pangidoan Batubara that have use brute force method (with times ranged from 1-5 days of testing) but my professor didnt want it because I cant find a paper that dictates how long 'ideally' a bruteforce should be performed (in the proposal that I write I said that I need 24 hours to do the brute forcing method due to the limited capability of my laptop).
So my question is what kind of test that I can implement in order to measure bcrypt security?
If somehow I have to prove the security of AES too, any kind of test that I can use?
A friendly reminder that I am using laravel to built this aes and bcrypt encrypt/decrypt app.

Comment: Well, [`bcrypt` isn't an encryption algorithm at all. It's a password-hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), so your premise is wrong to begin with.

Comment: What do you want to test? What do you want to measure? There are plenty of papers (mainly on AES) about the theoretical strength of each algorithm.  Encryption has different properties we consider as strong (key strength, resistance to different attacks ..) , hash has different properties (preimage resistance, collision resistance..).. though I'm not sure you can *test* the properties on a laptop until you have a few thousand/milions years in your disposal..  To get an image - how much performance you need to find a key with non-negligible probability for 128 bit and 256 bit key

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is crypto question that is best asked elsewhere, perhaps [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), if it's not already answered there already.

Comment: @AKX [there is a bcrypt file encryption utility](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) that confuses most...